# if/then else case statement query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create little complicated if then else case query. I picked an example for it to ask easier.
The table i have similar to this:

| apt | id | StartDay | EndDay | IN | OUT | WeekNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 208 | 12 | 6/6/2022 | 6/10/2022 | yes |  | 1 |
| 208 | 12 | 6/13/2022 | 6/17/2022 |  |  | 2 |
| 208 | 12 | 6/27/2022 | 7/1/2022 |  | yes | 3 |
| 304 | 55 | 6/6/2022 | 6/10/2022 | yes |  | 1 |

the goal is same id in one column and pull if 'IN' is 'yes' then startday, if 'out' is 'yes' then 'endday'.also create 2 variables with 'weekno' as weekstart and weekend.
Also if 'out' IS NULL, No need to see that 'id'
Whatever i tried didnt comeout in exact way that i need.

| apt | id | moveindate | moveoutdate | weekstart | weekend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 208 | 12 | 6/6/2022 | 7/1/2022 | 1 | 3 |  |

Tried if then else query didnt worked. i expect to find query for pull the 2nd table i created at the top.

Comment: To clarify: why no `3` for the `weekend` field in the results? And you don't want to see a row for `304`? So only show rows if both IN and OUT are present? Also, **NEVER** post images of sample data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: If moveout is null ,i dont need to see that id

Comment: Okay, what about the other question (not showing the WeekNo from the OUT record)? Also, can an `apt`/`id` group have more than one set of records?

Comment: Though about about left joining the table on its self, left join on the id and if "OUT" is yes. Then your just assigning IN to the first table (from table) and the second table (left join table) to OUT.

Comment: No, apt/id are unique. For weekno will be 2 variables, Weekstart and weekend. if in = yes then weekno will be weekstart. if out=yes then weekno will be weekEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition aggregation might solve it for you:

```sql
select apt, id
,   max(case when [in] = 'yes' then startday end) as inDate
,   max(case when [out] = 'yes' then endday end) as outDate
,   max(case when [in] = 'yes' then weekno end) as weekIn
,   max(case when [out] = 'yes' then weekno end) as weekOut

from (
    VALUES  (208, 12, N'6/6/2022', N'6/10/2022', N'yes', N'', 1)
    ,   (208, 12, N'6/13/2022', N'6/17/2022', N'', N'', 2)
    ,   (208, 12, N'6/27/2022', N'7/1/2022', N'', N'yes', 3)
    ,   (304, 55, N'6/6/2022',  N'6/10/2022',N'yes',N'', 1)
) t (apt,id,StartDay,EndDay,[IN],OUT,WeekNo)
where 'yes' IN ([IN], [OUT])
group by apt, id
HAVING SUM(case when [IN] = 'yes' then -1 else 1 end) = 0
```

This creates start and end columns by doing a CASE WHEN.

This won't work if you have multiple IN / Outs for same apt / id though, but it doesn't sound like you had that.

The count and where condition make sure you only get both rows

Comment: Ooh, I would have tried a self-join, but this should work and run faster to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Thought about left joining the table on its self? left join on the id and if "OUT" is yes. Then your just assigning IN to the first table (from table) and the second table (left join table) to OUT

```
SELECT startTable.apt, startTable.id, startTable.StartDay, endTable.EndDay, startTable.WeekNo, endTable.WeekNo 
FROM tablename AS startTable
LEFT JOIN tablename AS endTable
    ON endTable.id = startTable.id
    AND endTable.[OUT] = 'yes'
WHERE startTable.[IN] = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the case statement?

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN IN = 'yes' then 'startday',
WHEN OUT = 'yes' then 'endday'
ELSE 'NONE'
END AS day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by joining the relevant information from the table unto itself using INNER JOIN.

Essentially, we wish to retrieve the record for a particular ID where IN and OUT are equal - i.e. they both have a "yes" value.

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
select t1.apt, t1.id, t1.startday, t2.endday, t1.weekno as weekstart from
apartments as t1 inner join apartments as t2 on t1.IN=t2.OUT;
```

[image]